# Nginx on my VPS is continuously trying to access the Wordpress API using 0.0.0.0

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, centos7

I'm running a docker container with Wordpress, MYSQL and PHP on my Centos 7 VPS.

I can access the frontend of my blog fine. I can also log into the admin panel and install plugins, but when I try to save pages, save posts, or make any kind of update to them, I get the following errors:

[image]

However, if I manually replace 0.0.0.0:8000 with my domain name, e.g. domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/, then I don't get the error.

This is my Nginx setup:

```
server {

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

    if ( $http_host ~* "www\.(.*)") {
           return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I need to some how get Wordpress to use my domain at all times.

Answer (score 2):

Modify wp-config.php and add WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL.
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Or just change it on your database (inside wp_options)

Comment: I did this earlier and it didn't make a difference. Also, the entries in my database were already correct